CORS errors when testing the Function App hosted in Azure App Service Environment (ASE)
I have a function app hosted in Azure App Service Environment (ASE). When doing a Test/Run in the portal it keeps giving CORS error. Even though https://portal.azure.com is already added to allowed origins.


